# get serial number in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

AmountCartModel.java

```
public class AmountCartModel {


private String testName;
private String testPrice;
private String serialNumber;
private Integer totalPrice;


public AmountCartModel() {
    this.testName = testName;
    this.testPrice = testPrice;
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}


public String getTestName() {
    return testName;
}

public void setTestName(String testName) {
    this.testName = testName;
}

public String getTestPrice() {
    return testPrice;
}

public void setTestPrice(String testPrice) {
    this.testPrice = testPrice;
}

public String getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
}

public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}

public Integer getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

public void setTotalPrice(Integer totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}
```

}

AmountCartActivity.java

```
    public class AmountCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.total_price)
    TextView totalPriceDisplay;

    SharePreferenceManager<LoginModel> sharePreferenceManager;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<AmountCartModel> mydataList ;

    private MyAdapter madapter;

    Bundle extras ;
    String testName="";
    String testPrice="";
    String totalPrice= "";

    int counting = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_amount_cart);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getApplicationContext());


     showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));


        mydataList = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        * Getting Values From BUNDLE
        * */
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            testName = extras.getString("test_name");
            testPrice = extras.getString("test_price");
            totalPrice = String.valueOf(extras.getInt("total_price"));

            counting = extras.getInt("serialNumber");

            //Just add your data in list
            AmountCartModel mydata = new AmountCartModel();  // object of Model Class
            mydata.setTestName(testName );
            mydata.setTestPrice(testPrice);

            mydata.setTotalPrice(Integer.valueOf(totalPrice));

            mydata.setSerialNumber(counting);

            mydataList.add(mydata);


        }


        madapter=new MyAdapter(mydataList);
        madapter.setMyDataList(mydataList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyler_amount_cart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
}
}
```

AmountCartAdapter.java

```
     public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> 
    {

        private List<AmountCartModel> context;
        private List<AmountCartModel> myDataList;

        public MyAdapter(List<AmountCartModel> context) {
            this.context = context;
            myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        }



       @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
    {

            // Replace with your layout
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.amount_cart_row, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // Set Your Data here to yout Layout Components..

            // to get Amount
           /* myDataList.get(position).getTestName();
            myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice();*/


            holder.testName.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestName());

       holder.testPrice.setText(myDataList.get(position).getTestPrice());

       holder.textView2.setText(myDataList.get(position).getSerialNumber());


        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            /*if (myDataList.size() != 0) {
                // return Size of List if not empty!
                return myDataList.size();
            }
            return 0;*/
            return myDataList.size();
        }


        public void setMyDataList(List<AmountCartModel> myDataList) {
            // getting list from Fragment.
            this.myDataList = myDataList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView testName,testPrice,textView2;


            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                // itemView.findViewById

                testName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name_one);
                testPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_price);
                textView2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        startActivity(new 
     Intent(AmountCartActivity.this,HealthServicesActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    }
```

HealthCartActivity

```
 public class HealthServicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private ImageView imlogo;
    private TextView Date;
    private TextView Time;
    private TextView Day;

    private ImageView settingsButton;

    @BindView(R.id.back_to_add_patient)
    TextView backToDashboard;

    int totalAmount = 0;
    int totalPrice = 0;
    String testName = "";
    String testPrice = "";
    int count = 0;

    /*
    *Api call
    * */
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<TestListModel> mydataList;
    private RecyclerAdapter madapter;


    private ArrayList<TestListModel> mydb;

    private Button submitButton;

    private TextView deviceModeName;
    private TextView centerId;

    SharePreferenceManager<LoginModel> sharePreferenceManager;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_services);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getApplicationContext());


        imlogo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_logo);
        Day=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
        Date=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        Time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
        //backButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        centerId=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.center_id);
        deviceModeName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.device_mode_name);

        settingsButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.settings);

        submitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

        dayTimeDisplay();

        showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));


        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(HealthServicesActivity.this, settingsButton);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater()
                        .inflate(R.menu.common_navigation_menu, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        int id = item.getItemId();

                        if (id==R.id.home){

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashBoardActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }

                        if (id==R.id.my_profile){

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyProfileActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }

                        if (id==R.id.change_password){

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChangePasswordActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(HealthServicesActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show(); //showing popup menu

            }
        });


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(HealthServicesActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        //registerOnline();

        initViews();

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        backToDashboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    /*
    * Action Bar DATE N TIME
    * */
    private void dayTimeDisplay(){

        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        java.util.Date d = new Date();
        String dayOfTheWeek = sdf1.format(d);
        Day.setText(dayOfTheWeek);

        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        Date.setText(currentDateTimeString);

        Date dt = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        String time1 = sdf.format(dt);
        Time.setText(time1);

    }


    /*
    * On Click Listner
    * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.submit_button:

                        AtomicInteger sharedOutput = new AtomicInteger(0);

                        List<TestListModel> stList = ((RecyclerAdapter) madapter)
                                .getTestList();


                       for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                            TestListModel singleStudent = stList.get(i);

                           if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

                               //testListId = testListId+ "\n" + singleStudent.getTestlist_id().toString();

                               testName = testName + "\n" + singleStudent.getTest_name().toString();
                               testPrice = testPrice+"\n" + singleStudent.getTest_price().toString();

                                //count = singleStudent.setSerial_number("\n" +i);

                                //singleStudent.getSerial_number(count);

                               count ++;


                               /* count = sharedOutput.get() + 1;
                                System.out.println(count);
                                sharedOutput.incrementAndGet();*/

                                totalAmount = Integer.parseInt(stList.get(i).getTest_price());

                                totalPrice = totalPrice + totalAmount;


                            }
                       }




                        Toast.makeText(HealthServicesActivity.this,
                                "Selected Lists: \n" + testName+ "" + testPrice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();


                        Intent in= new Intent(HealthServicesActivity.this, AmountCartActivity.class);


                        in.putExtra("test_name", testName);
                        in.putExtra("test_price", testPrice);
                        in.putExtra("total_price", totalPrice);
                        in.putExtra("serial_number", count);



                        startActivity(in);

                        finish();

                        break;



                    /** back Button Click
                    * */
                    case R.id.back_to_add_patient:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PatientActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;


            default:
                break;

        }
    }



    /** show center Id in action bar
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showcenterid(sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class));


    }


    private void showcenterid(LoginModel userLoginData) {
        centerId.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getGenCenterId());
        centerId.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getGenCenterId().toUpperCase());
        deviceModeName.setText(userLoginData.getResult().getDeviceModeName());
    }


    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.test_list_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }


    private void loadJSON() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/")
//                .baseUrl("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface request = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getTestLists();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {


                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                mydataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getResult()));
                madapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mydataList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }


}
```

I am trying to display serial number to my AmountCartActivity of recycler view whichever I am selecting from previous HealthCartActivity using checkbox. And, I have implemented some code but I am not getting how to get the serial number.

Comment: You should add a `serialNumber` field to your `AmountCartModel`.

Comment: i have added previously but after getting serial number value it was giving me null

Comment: did you getting the data from intent ?

Comment: I have edited my code, added previous Activity i.e. HealthCartActivity. I am getting count value but not getting serial number

Comment: holder.textView2.setText(myDataList.get(position).getSerialNumber());
holder.textView2.setText(myDataList.get(position+1).getSerialNumber());
Can share the reason for setting  getSerialNumber to same textview??

Comment: Ohh Sorry i have done that by mistake while updating my question. I am removing it.

Comment: won't your list `AmountCartModel ` have only 1 item since you are adding just 1 item to it?

Comment: Set this mydata.setSerialNumber(String.valueOf(counting)); as your serial number is string in AmountCartModel.

Comment: I am not getting your point @samirk433

Comment: its giving me null value @Jay

Comment: Your list has only 1 item, right? we can't see where are you feeding data to the adapter. Also, do you have a custom serial number pattern or it should start from 1

Comment: In my list there are many items. I am feeding data to adapter through API call. And, no i don't have any custom serial pattern. @samirk433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have done code for serial number like below. Here I am getting serial number in front of the elements. In this code I took one int variable and initialized with value 1. After that I call srNo variable in for loop then incremented at the end of the for loop.

```
 int srNo = 1;
  List < TestListModel > stList = ((RecyclerAdapter) madapter)
   .getTestList();

  for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
   TestListModel singleStudent = stList.get(i);

   if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

    testListId = testListId + "\n" + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(srNo));
    testName = testName + "\n" + singleStudent.getTest_name().toString();
    testPrice = testPrice + "\n" + singleStudent.getTest_price().toString();

    srNo++;

    totalAmount = Integer.parseInt(stList.get(i).getTest_price());
    totalPrice = totalPrice + totalAmount;


   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can work-around. And you won't have to keep `serialNumber` variable in model just to track it's position.

You can use `position` parameter variable of `onBindViewHolder()` for serial number and counting.

i.e.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     //here position is unique for every item in the list, so, you can use it as a serial number
    // also, since it's starting from 0, you should add 1 with it, in case you wanna start from 1      

    // holder.textView2.setText(myDataList.get(position).getSerialNumber());
       holder.textView2.setText("S.No. "+(position+1));
 }
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to display single item's position. I want to display every item's position as serial number

Comment: did with the same thing as you say but it's not working properly for me

Comment: what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
    holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(" "+(position+1)));
```

Use above method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `serialNumber` to your `AmountCartModel`.This will fix your problem

Comment: I have done it already. please see my question, Still im stucked in it

Answer (score 0):

Put an id in your AmountCartModel as below;

```
public class AmountCartModel {

private int serialNumber; // add this line
private String testName;
private String testPrice;
private Integer totalPrice;


public AmountCartModel() {
    this.serialNumber= serialNumber; // add this line
    this.testName = testName;
    this.testPrice = testPrice;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}

public int getSerialNumber (){
} // add this line

public void setSerialNumber(int serialNumber) {
}// add this line also
```

Then retrieve this serialNumber from each view.
Since you are sending the intent form onBackPressed(); attach the list as an extra to the intent as follows,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    startActivity(new 
 Intent(AmountCartActivity.this,HealthServicesActivity.class).putParcelableArrayList("the list", mDataList));
    finish();
}
```

Please ensure the object (AmountCarModel) you are making a list from extends Parcelable, and catch it in the HealthServiceActivity in onResume()

Alternatively, and probably the best way, is to attach the serialNumber inside the HealthServiceActivity in the Retrofit onResponse() method as below;

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getResult()));
            if (data != null){ 
                for (int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++) {
                     data.setSerialNumber(i);}}
            madapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

        }
```

Comment: set the serialNumber and catch it

Comment: i have set the serial number and I am catching it already, please see my updated question

Comment: It's working here, maybe there you forgot to put ; or } etc, please review your code well

Comment: No, i put the code in correct way, but it's giving setSerialNumber(i) as error. its not setting the serialNumber

Answer (score 0):

In AmountCartModel serialNumber is of String datatype

and while putting object you are setting 
   counting = extras.getInt("serialNumber");

```
        //Just add your data in list
        AmountCartModel mydata = new AmountCartModel();  // object of Model Class
        mydata.setTestName(testName );
        mydata.setTestPrice(testPrice);

        mydata.setTotalPrice(Integer.valueOf(totalPrice));

        mydata.setSerialNumber(counting);
```

and you are storing it in ArrayList  without for loop so every time only one object will get inclued in your arraylist

Answer (score 0):

try  this way

```
int count = 0;
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.submit_button:

                        int totalAmount = 0;
                        int totalPrice = 0;
                        String testName = "";
                        String testPrice="";




                        List<TestListModel> stList = ((RecyclerAdapter) madapter)
                                .getTestList();


                       for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                            TestListModel singleStudent = stList.get(i);

                           //AmountCartModel serialNumber = stList.get(i);


                           if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {

                                testName = testName + "\n" + singleStudent.getTest_name().toString();
                                testPrice = testPrice+"\n" + singleStudent.getTest_price().toString();


                                count++;

                                totalAmount = Integer.parseInt(stList.get(i).getTest_price());

                                totalPrice = totalPrice + totalAmount;

                            }
                       }


                        Toast.makeText(HealthServicesActivity.this,
                                "Selected Lists: \n" + testName+ "" + testPrice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();


                        Intent in= new Intent(HealthServicesActivity.this, AmountCartActivity.class);

                        in.putExtra("test_name", testName);
                        in.putExtra("test_price", testPrice);
                        in.putExtra("total_price", totalPrice);
                        in.putExtra("serialNumber", count);
                        startActivity(in);

                        finish();

                        break;



                    /** back Button Click
                    * */
                    case R.id.back_to_add_patient:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PatientActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    break;


            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried the same way but getting single number as 1 in that field

Comment: @Shruti B you are getting 1 because when singleStudent.isSelected() is true count=1, and you are passing that only.So you are getting correct value of serialNumber and every time when submit  button clicked count will be 0 every time and if singleStudent.isSelected() true count will be 1

Comment: You are right and I am getting the value 1 as count. but when i am selecting 4 checkbox then it should give me 1 2 3 4 in serial manner

Comment: @Shruti B i have edited my answer.initialize count outside on click

Comment: i have updated HealthCartActivity code. I have initialized count outside onClick, but still not working

Comment: @Shruti B if you want to 1 2 3 4 all then you need to store count in one array and pass that array with intent